# Explaining intersections to a 6th grader

Tags: elementary-set-theory, education, learning

$A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$

$B=\emptyset$

How to explain to a learner from 6th grade the result for $A \cap B$ ?

For a 6th grade student, it could be difficult to understand why the result is $\emptyset$. Most of them might think like this: *...well, the result is what both $A$ and $B$ have, but does the $A$ set contain the $\emptyset$* ?

It will be great to explain with some day-by-day examples, examples from real life and so on.

Comment: maybe focus on the definition of the intersection. say that the intersection is the set that contains all the elements that are in both sets. and there are non. since there are no elements in $\emptyset$

Comment: If school dress requires you to wear black shoes with white socks and student 1,2,3,4,5 wore black shoes but non of them wore white socks, how many students are in complete uniform?

Comment: The confusion that you’re envisioning arises from the ambiguity of *contains*: in everyday language it can mean either $\in$ or $\subseteq$. If there really is a problem with this, you might be better off starting out using $\{\}$ for the empty set: then you’re looking for $\{\ldots\}$, where $\ldots$ is the list of things that are listed in both $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $\{\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming he already knows what an empty set is, it should not be too hard.

Usually, a good way to represent sets is bags with things in them, and an empty set is just a bag with nothing in it.

Now, you can represent an intersection of sets with picking common things. So if one bag has eggs, flour and butter and the other has butter, milk and bread, the intersection of them is a bag which has things that are in both bags, so it has milk.

An intersection of a bag with milk and eggs and a bag with bread and butter is then an empty bag, because no object is in both sets.

Now in your case, one bag is empty, so the intersection with this bag is empty, because nothing can go into the intersection because nothing is in the empty bag.

Comment: Nice explanation. So a full bag by "definition" contains an empty bag.

Comment: @FlorinM. Well, no. Just like some sets do not contain the empty set. For example, $\mathbb R$ does not contain $\emptyset$. It is, however, true that $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of all sets. In analogy, that would mean that a full bag always contains all items in an empty bag.

Comment: @FlorinM. There is a bit of confusion around the terminology of “contains”.  There are two relations here.  A set $A$ can be a subset of set $B$, and an object $x$ can be an element of a set $B$.  The word “contains” is unfortunately used for both relations, although set theory is careful to distinguish them.  The set $\emptyset$ is a *subset* of every set $B$, but it is not an *element* of every set. It is an element of the set of all things discussed in this comment, but it is not an element of the set of monarchs of England, because it is not a monarch of England.